# Netty write to all connected channels

Tags: java, netty

I need some advice how to implement a netty server which gets data from some source(files for example) and then sends it as strings to all connected clients. I'd like to have class Server and invoke method broadcast on an object of this class. It should be used like this:

```
Server server = new Server();
String message;

while (true) {
    message = getMessage();
    server.broadcast(message);
}
```

I know that for this purpose I can use ChannelGroup however I don't know how to prevent channel write buffer from being exceeded (I don't know how to use channel.isWritable()).

```
ChannelGroup broadcast = new DefaultChannelGroup("broadcast");

...

public void broadcast(String message) {
    for (Channel channel : broadcast) {
        if (channel.isWritable())
            channel.write(message);
    }
}
```

Above solution is wrong because I want each message to be delivered to each client. I'd appreciate some advice how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If by *delivered to each client* you mean that you need to send it to each client, then the easiest technique is to use the methods on [ChannelGroup](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html) itself. The writeAndFlush method (write method if netty 3.x) returns a future that will be signalled when the message has been flushed to all channels in the group.

```
ChannelGroupFuture future = broadcast.writeAndFlush(message);
future.awaitUninterruptibly();
```

You can use the methods of [ChannelGroupFuture](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroupFuture.html) to determine if the message was written all channels, and to figure out which channels failed.

This will limit you to the performance of the slowest channel but your example code implies that's ok. Having individual channels run at full speed, or knowing the message was actually delivered, increases the scope dramatically.

Comment: True, I should've been more specific. By delivered to each client I meant only that for each client and each message channel.write(message) will be invoked. Your solution is correct but it would be slowly. I'd like each channel to run at full speed and when channel is too slow I'd like it to be disconnected. My example code was just an example, if it can be done better I'd be more than happy to do it. Can you tell me how you would approach this problem?

Comment: A crude option is something like your original code. When the channel is created, set the write high water mark to the maximum number of bytes you will allow a channel to fall behind. If channel.isWritable returns false the channel is too slow and should be closed. The low water mark is irrelevant. For a backlog of messages, rather than bytes, perhaps a pipeline handler that checked if it was waiting on a write to complete, and queue a message. It listens on the write future to send the next message. If the queue is too large it closes the channel.